# Java: the length of the byte array seems to be wrong from converting a string of binary

Tags: java, arrays, binary, byte, bit

I am trying to do bits padding to a byte array, and the number of bits that I need to pad is 48 (so 6 bytes). Below is the binary string:

```
String paddingBinaryString = "100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

However, the byte array from this binary string shows the length to be 7 (instead of 6!). The way I convert the 48-bit binary String to byte array is:

```
byte[] paddingByteArr = new BigInteger(paddingBinaryString, 2).toByteArray();
System.out.println("paddingByteArr.length: " + paddingByteArr.length); //shows 7
```

There must be something obviously wrong, because 48 bits must be 6 bytes, not 7, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray--) for `toByteArray` says

> The array will contain the minimum number of bytes required to represent this BigInteger, **including at least one sign bit**

The number is positive so at least one extra zero has to be added at the beginning, requiring a whole extra byte. The representation is big endian, so the resulting array is

```
00000000 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
       ^
       |
       *--- sign bit
```

Comment: So, if you remove one zero from original string, it will become 6-byte.